# How to tell if java client request *might* have been received by server

Tags: java, network-programming, client-server

I have a Java client application that makes requests to a server API.

In cases of network errors during the request/response, if there is ***any  chance*** that the server received the request, I need to assume that the request was received.

However, if I can be **100% certain that the server did not receive the request**, I need to treat the request as failed.

My question is, is there some logic around the types and/or details of the IOException subclasses thrown by the java.net package that I can use to determine if the request ***definitively did not reach the server*** (eg. that a socket was not created or no data was sent)?

At the moment I have the following, but as you can see, this isn't comprehensive, nor very reassuring (using the exception message to differentiate read & closed connection timeouts):

```
/**
 * This returns true if the exception is a network timeout that happened BEFORE the server received any data
 * @param e  The exception that was thrown
 * @return true if the exception is a network timeout that happened BEFORE the server received any data
 */
public static boolean isDefinitivePreConnectionNetworkError(Exception e) {

    //return true for all java.net.SocketException and java.io.InterruptedIOException that don't have the word "read" or "closed" in their message (case insensitive)

    if(!e.getClass().isAssignableFrom(IOException.class) || ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(e).getClass().isAssignableFrom(IOException.class)) {

        return false;
    }

    String message = e.getMessage();

    Throwable eRoot = ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(e);

    String messageRoot = eRoot == null ? message : eRoot.getMessage();

    message = message == null ? "" : message.toLowerCase();
    messageRoot = messageRoot == null ? "" : messageRoot.toLowerCase();

    if(messageRoot.contains("read")
        || message.contains("read")
        || messageRoot.contains("closed")
            || message.contains("closed")) {

        return false;
    }

    return (eRoot instanceof java.net.SocketException
            || eRoot instanceof java.io.InterruptedIOException
            || e instanceof java.net.SocketException
            || e instanceof java.io.InterruptedIOException
    );
}
```

Comment: Why don't the 'normal' I/O exceptions suffice for you? If any of these exceptions are raised then your data transfer to the server will have failed. Your server could return a response telling the client that the data has been received and processed, until that the client must assume that it could not correctly send the data.

Comment: @M.leRutte I don't control the server. I need to know if server *might* have received *any* data.  It's not clear which I/O exceptions indicate that. Eg. a socket exception with "read timeout", likely means server received data but takes long to respond, yet one indicating a "connect timeout" likely means that the socket creation failed so the server didn't receive data.

I may be the case that there may be some IOException subtypes for which I cannot be sure one way or another, but I'd like to be able to treat as many cases as possible where I can be certain the server didn't receive data.